# Why won't my Excel external links work when they work in original I copied?

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to validate data moved to a new server, through reports using old and new data. I copied the old report, and then went in to change the location. Everything looks good, I used the function wizard to make sure I had no typing / syntax errors, but I still get a #VALUE error.

The query:

```
=SUMIFS('EXTERNAL\[Report.xlsx]RPT_DATA'!$I:$I,
'EXTERNAL\[Report.xlsx]RPT_DATA'!$B:$B,$A$3,
'EXTERNAL\[Report.xlsx]RPT_DATA'!$C:$C,$C$6,
'EXTERNAL\[Report.xlsx]RPT_DATA'!$A:$A,"ACT")
```

All the criteria types match to the range, I have tried it with the external file open and not, and I just can't see what I'm doing wrong, since I copied it exactly from the existing report and JUST changed the external file to a different external file in the same location (essentially, from Q:\OldSource to Q:\NewSource - these are copies of the original and new, placed in the same "working" folder).

Any hints for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I had a stray _.

Dagnabbit